# Android - method must be called from the UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading

[problem with UI thread is solved]

I want to take picture in background thread and then send it to server and after that I want to receive response from server

Problem is that taking picture part is good, sending to server also is good but receiving response doesn't work. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the code that accesses UI elements in the `onPostExecute` callback method. But since you also need access to the `Bitmap` object - I'd suggest changing your `AsyncTask` class definition to include `Bitmap` as a 3rd parameter.

```
class TakePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, Bitmap> {
     @Override
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
       //since we want to decode the entire byte-array and not just 0th byte
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
         if (bitmap == null) {
             return null;
         }
         //the rest of your code/logic goes here...
         return bitmap;
       }
```

Then in your post-execute method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap  bitmap) {
  if(bitmap == null ){return; }
  capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(scaleDownBitmapImage(bitmap, 400, 400));
     try {
          //I am not sure what the purpose of this section of the code is...
          //so I just left it here
          Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) capturedImageHolder.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
          ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
          byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();
          final String tmp = Base64.encodeToString(array, Base64.NO_WRAP);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  showDialog("Image Taken ?");
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: it is returning null, what return type `onPostExecute` and `doInBackground` should have ?

Comment: I get this: `D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - the `doInBackground` should return `Bitmap`, not `Void`. I have changed the code, please try it again.

Comment: I figure it out myself but still get `D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`

Comment: probably because this must look like this: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data[0], 0, data[0].length);` ---> `data[0].length` instead of `data.length`

Comment: Check that `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` does not return null - I suspect this might be the issue.

Comment: Any luck after the changes?

Comment: Noted. I have made minor changes - I changed `data[0]` to just `data` because you'd want to decode the entire byte-array and not just the 0th byte. Give this a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: ok, I have updated the code but now I have new problem :/ I want to take picture(it works), send it to server(also it work) and then I want to receive response and this part doesn't work. Do you have any ideas why ?

Comment: I am glad the taking of pictures works - let's do this; please accept the answer here so that this question can be marked as answered, and then post a separate question for the server response issue - and also include the relevant piece of your code ( I feel it is a different issue altogether).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot update UI(views) from a background thread(doInBackground in this case), 
override onPostExecute and there call this `capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(scaleDownBitmapImage(bitmap, 400, 400));`

```
        class TakePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, Bitmap> {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data[0], 0, data.length);
                    if (bitmap == null) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Captured image is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return null;
                    }

                    //capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(scaleDownBitmapImage(bitmap, 400, 400));
                    try {
                        Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) capturedImageHolder.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                        byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();
                        final String tmp = Base64.encodeToString(array, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return bitmap;
                }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(scaleDownBitmapImage(bitmap, 400, 400));
            }
}
```

Comment: ok, but what with this `Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) capturedImageHolder.getDrawable()).getBitmap();` ?? can you show me how it should looks like ?

Comment: you already have bitmap reference on 1st line
`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data[0], 0, data.length);`